# Jolt transform to flatten a array in Nifi

Tags: arrays, json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have the following input JSON :

```json
{
  "a":[1,2,3,[4,5,6], [7], [8,9], 10, 11]
}
```

And I would like the output to be :

```json
{
  "a":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
}
```

What can be jolt transform for this. Thanks!

Comment: Use `Array.flat()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply consecutive **shift** transformations starting by seperating the elements to two arrays, one of which has sub-arrays, and the other has integers, namely `x` and `y` arrays . Then combine them while removing the `null` values, and convert stringified elements back to integers such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "a": {
        "*": {
          "@": "x.[@1]",
          "*": "y.[]"
        }
      }
    }
 },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$1": "@1"
        }
      }
    }
 },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "@(0)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "a"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=toInteger"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Perfect solution

Answer (score -1):

Try this If you need solution without using builtin function ! Obviously programming is what we solve the problems with logic without using packages and builtin function.

Note: This solution is actually in Javascript. I didn't noticed tags. Sorry

```js
const temp = {
  a: [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9], 10, 11]
};

let items = [];

temp.a.forEach((item) => {
  items = [
    ...items,
    ...(item.constructor.name === "Array" ? item : [item])
  ];
});
console.log(items);
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad, your answer seems to be for a Javascript question contrary to the current tags.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan yes this is actually done in the javascript. I didn't noticed the tags. But solution works in javascript haha